# Shield board with holes, do I need to solder?

Tags: arduino-mega, shields, arduino-motor-shield

I have a motor shield.
I can put it on top of my arduino Mega and works perfect.

However, since the shield plugs in on top of the arduino board, I don't have access to 5V and GND from Arduino Mega.

I just have holes on the board with 5V and GND. (look at image)[image]

Do I have to solder a cable there to have access to 5V and GND? or there is another easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are two grounds, a 2-pin terminal block of the type already on the board may fit. Or, since the shield doesn't obscure the far end of the Mega (the end with the high numbered I/Os), you could pick up 5V and Gnd there. The ends of the double-row female header have respectively, 2 each 5V and Gnd connectors. You would pick those up with breadboard wires, though it is admittedly less secure.

Comment: do you mean that the 2 female header after 52 and 53 are 5v and GND ? (on the bottom right corner of my image)

Comment: Below 52,53 are both ground. Above 22,23 are both 5V. It also written on the board.

Comment: ... in _tiny_ script! It's easy to miss.

Comment: It also looks like, to the right of the yellow square, are 3 rows of through-board holes. Labelled: +5V, Gnd, and A0 to A5. You could remove the shield temporarily, and solder on a couple of rows of sockets there, giving you 6 x +5V and 6 x Gnd connectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Mega Screw Shield if you don't want to solder wires
[image]